# Show hidden label by button click inside tableView Cell (expand/collapse cell)

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uikit

I have a stackView(vertical) which contains labels and bottom description label is hidden by default. And I implemented an arrow button at the right side of the cell. By clicking the button, I just want to show the hidden description label and stackView should expand automatically and make cell bigger. This was my basic idea to implement expandable cell.
So this is the code I used to get desired results:

```
@objc func downArrowButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton){
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        selectedIndex = indexPath
        selectedCellIndex = sender.tag
        isDescHidden = !isDescHidden
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
```

Above is the code for the button inside clicked cell. I went with the idea to reload that particular index. I created a variable named `selectedCellIndex` of in which I use  in `cellForRowAt` method to make some changes.

I also had the implement some code in viewDidLayoutSubviews() as when I first clicked the cell wasn't getting expanded fully. here's that just in case:

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let indexPath = selectedIndex
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath ?? IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }
```

And calling it in `willDisplay` method which finally fixed the cell expansion issue:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }
```

And here is my `cellForRowAt` function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
            
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                cell.lblTitle.text = "Title 1"
                cell.lblDesc.text = "Desc 1"
            }
            else if indexPath.row == 1 {
                cell.lblTitle.text = "Title 2"
                cell.lblDesc.text = "Desc 2"
            }
            else {
                cell.lblTitle.text = "Title 3"
                cell.lblDesc.text = "Desc 3"
            }
            
            if selectedCellIndex != nil {
                if isDescHidden == false {
                    if cell.isDescHidden == true {
                        cell.lblDesc.isHidden = false
                        cell.btnArrow.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.up"), for: .normal)
                    }
                    else {
                        cell.lblDesc.isHidden = true
                        cell.btnArrow.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down"), for: .normal)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if cell.isDescHidden == true {
                        cell.lblDesc.isHidden = true
                        cell.btnArrow.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down"), for: .normal)
                    }
                    else {
                        cell.lblDesc.isHidden = false
                        cell.btnArrow.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.up"), for: .normal)
                    }
                }
                cell.isDescHidden = !cell.isDescHidden
            }
            
            cell.btnArrow.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.btnArrow.addTarget(self, action: #selector(downArrowButtonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            
            return cell
    }
```

This approach gets too confusing as you can see from the above code. The `isDescHidden` variable is defined in both Main view controller as well as table view cell class and I was trying to use both to expand or collapse a particular cell. However first time it works but if I have 3 cells expanded, collapsing button click doesn't work for 1-2 clicks then works.

Is there a better approach for this kind of problem? Or is there any way I can directly set `cell.isDescHidden` value from `@objc func downArrowButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton)` function? So I can use that in `cellForRowAt` function?
I would be glad if I could directly make changes to cell variables from that.

Comment: Why not encapsulating this in `CustomTableViewCell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following function for automatic height for rows and provided `top` and `bottom` constraints to your `stackView`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

Here is my CustomCell

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleCell: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detail: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var arrowButton: UIButton!

    let upArrow = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.up.circle.fill")
    let downArrow = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down.circle.fill")
    var onArrowClick: ((UIButton)->())!
    
    @IBAction func handleArrowButton(sender: UIButton){
        onArrowClick(sender)
    }

    func updateArrowImage(expandStatus: Bool){
        arrowButton.setImage(expandStatus ? downArrow : upArrow, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

For sample Data

```
   let data = [
        ["Nothing", "description is very long description is very long description is very long description is very  "],
        ["Nothing", "description is very long "],
        ["Nothing", "description is very long "],
        ["Nothing", "description is very long "],
        ["Nothing", "description is very long "]
    ]

var eachCellStatus: [Bool] = []

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     tableView.dataSource = self
     tableView.delegate = self
     for _ in data {
         eachCellStatus.append(true)
     }
}
```

TableView methods are like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomCell
        cell.titleCell.text = data[indexPath.row][0]
        cell.detail.text = data[indexPath.row][1]
        cell.detail.isHidden = eachCellStatus[indexPath.row]
        cell.updateArrowImage(expandStatus: self.eachCellStatus[indexPath.row])
        cell.onArrowClick = { button in
            self.eachCellStatus[indexPath.row].toggle()
            cell.updateArrowImage(expandStatus: self.eachCellStatus[indexPath.row])
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: arrow image change and I think the description toggles too but cell does not expand. My title moves up a bit with top of desc showed but row size remains fixed. I implemented everything as above, even function to automatically adjust tableview dimension

Comment: Have you provided `top` and `bottom` constraints to your `stackView`. these are required for automaticDimension.

Comment: yes I have provided stack view constraints in every direction

Comment: I have updated the above code with `var eachCellStatus: [Bool] = []` initially status for each cell will be false and then will be updated on the arrow button click, try this out its working for me.

Comment: works better but buttons are updating randomly. and when I set initial state ti hidden as I want to load table with hidden details, the first time I click, cell is still not expanding fully. Just like before halfway. but on second click, it works fine

Comment: @Mel I have updated the above code(CustomCell and cellForRowAt method) to handle arrow button icons.

Comment: If the answer is helpful, then upvote/accept this answer so others can get benefits as well.

Comment: okay it works smoothly now but that first time clicking still doesn't expand cell, changes button icon, detail unhides but cell row height remains same, then if I click other cells or collapse it and click button again, everything works fine. I will just add some code for cell layout & should be good to go

Comment: maybe you tableView row is not reloading properly, try `tableview.reloadData()`

Comment: yes it worked. Just needed to reload whole table instead of reloading row

Answer (score 0):

First create a model to show data into cell. You have to preserve the state of cell.

```
struct CellData {
    var title: String
    var details: String
    var isExpanded: Bool
}
```

In `CustomTableViewCell` add a property for cellData and assign `Outlet`s data from it. Also create a `protocol` to reload `row` from `UIViewController`

```
protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate {
    func reloadRow(sender: CustomTableViewCell, flag: Bool)
}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var showButton: UIButton!
    
    var indexPath: IndexPath?
    var delegate: CustomTableViewCellDelegate?
    
    var data: CellData? {
        didSet {
            
            if let data = data {
                if data.isExpanded == false {
                    detailsLabel.isHidden = true
                    showButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down"), for: .normal)
                    
                }else {
                    detailsLabel.isHidden = true
                    showButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.up"), for: .normal)
                }
                
                titleLabel.text = data.title
                detailsLabel.text = data.details
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        titleLabel.text = nil
        detailsLabel.text = nil
    }
    
    @IBAction func showButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if var data = data {
            data.isExpanded.toggle()
            delegate?.reloadRow(cell: self, flag: data.isExpanded)
        }
    }
}
```

In `UIViewController` add an array of `CellData` type. You may assign it's data in `viewDidLoad()` method.

```
var tableData: [CellData]
```

Modify `numberOfRowsInSection()` and `cellForRow()` method like bleow.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.data = tableData[indexPath.row]
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Then confirm `CustomTableViewCellDelegate` protocol to `UIViewController`

```
extension ViewController: CustomTableViewCellDelegate {
    func reloadRow(sender: CustomTableViewCell, isExpanded: Bool) {
        guard let tappedIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender) else { return }
        tableData[tappedIndexPath.row].isExpanded = isExpanded
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have data model. well I can make and this solution seems good but would prefer for some static 2-3 cells for now